# Is there any page limit or fee for "Applicant Arguments/Remarks Made in an Amendment"?

Tags: uspto, prosecution, amendment

I would like to embed images in the "Applicant Arguments/Remarks" to explain myself clearly.

1. Can I use images (preferably color) in "Applicant Arguments/Remarks"?
2. Is there any page limit for "Applicant Arguments/Remarks"? [I feel like there is some limit since examiner time will be utilised here]
3. Is there any fee or excess fee?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use drawings and there is no page limit or excess page fee. Of course you need to understand that you are trying to convince and less might be more. It may be difficult to get color images through the system.

You may be able to get an interview over Webex or whatever the approved system the USPTO is currently using at which time you can hold up your color drawings.